# How would a species in one dimension with its own properties go to another dimension with slightly different properties?

Tags: physics, alternate-worlds, fantasy-races, transportation, dimensions

In my world, I have three dimensions, each of which have their own special properties. From each of these three dimensions come a master race of said dimension:

1. From the first, the master race is a creature who can manipulate their atomic structure to match that of anything they touch for long enough.
2. For the second dimension, the master race is a people who look mostly like floating fog, with no visible body appendages. Their main ability is to generate appendages from this smoke.
3. From the third, you have your regular old human, who is nothing more than simply a human. This human's world simply has a much more advanced technology base then we would imagine and also have discovered the existence of tachyons.

**Explanation of Dimensions:**

> The explanation appears in the order that the dimensions were mentioned.

1. This race resides in a dimension much like our own Earth. The major difference here is that the massive amount of adaptation through transformation has to lead to massive species wars with many species transforming into stars, asteroids, and space rocks to cause severe damage to enemy lines. Since these battles span multiple galaxies, this has caused much galactical instability, leading to frequent supernovas.
2. The second race resides in a dimension that lacks light. The beings in this dimension primarily move through sensory perception (smell, touch, feel, and they have the ability to sense anything dangerous to them). The nature of their dimension is without solid matter and light.
   a. For anybody who is wondering how the beings in this dimension are mobile, remember that at their base, they are almost weightless. They also have the ability to manipulate the "smoke" from which they are, so they can use it to create a light lift, ascending, descending, accelerating forward and so on to move around.
3. The final dimension has the special nature of understanding and manipulating tachyons. Their main feat is the ability to time travel by harnessing the tachyonic energy found in space.

How would each of these races be able to transport themselves to the other dimensions?

Comment: Are you fishing for ideas?

Comment: Not exactly. I am trying to figure out if their is a logical way to get from one dimension to the other, so that this logical process can be inhibited by people from other dimensions @RonJohn. In a sense, I am kind of blank in the physics department (if that is what this translates to) and I was wondering if anybody else had a plausible explanation.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the dimensions they inhabit? I suspect that that’s more pertinent than the races trying to travel through them.

Comment: Physics says you should tack the words "to permeate the quantum membrane" to your story and call that good enough.

Comment: "*is a logical way to get from one dimension to the other*"? Using technology, or as part of their biology?

Comment: I think it is very difficult to answer such a question without understanding the physics of how your dimensions are separated.  Also, what criteria would you give for deciding a better answer from a worse one?  Is this just a "rule of cool" world where as long as the idea seems clever, we can ignore all the physics required to make it happen?

Comment: @CortAmmon I did update the question to include the brief overview of the physics in the other worlds.

Comment: @RonJohn one or both will be fine.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mansoor. Could you take another look at your question title? It seems to be different from your question body and I'm having trouble reconciling the discrepancy.

Comment: @Frostfyre There. I hope that does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are not too concerned with real physics.  For instance, physicists use the term "dimension" to describe something different from that which is often used in science fiction.  I point this out because this suggests you should be looking for solutions that look and feel more like magic.  I highly recommend [Sanderson's First Law](https://brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-first-law/) for this:

> **Sanderson’s First Law of Magics:** An author’s ability to solve conflict with magic is DIRECTLY PROPORTIONAL to how well the reader understands said magic.

The really neat thing about this law is that it works well for all sorts of things, not just high fantasy magic.  You have a species which is nothing but pure fog?  The ability to solve conflict through them is based on how well the reader understands them.

Note the key phrase, "solve conflict."  You can get away with a great deal of funny ill-defined magic when you create conflict, but when you try to solve conflict with magic, you better pay attention to how well the reader understands the magic.  Otherwise they'll feel cheated.

From your descriptions of the species and the dimensions, I can tell where you will be focusing the flavor of your story.  You wont be too worried about whether, say, angular momentum is conserved while phasing out of the first dimension into the next.  You're going to be focused on the carnage caused by the abilities of the denzens of this first dimension.  Thus if you tie the phasing abilities to the ability to cause carnage, you'll have something that fits well with Sanderson's First Law.

I'd start by having shards of material from other dimensions found in the 1st dimension.  No explanation why, other than that it's relatively clear the masters of this dimension did not create them.  They aren't creators.  They are destroyers.  Touch the material long enough, and it phases you out into the other dimensions.  Of course, you'll want to decide whether they retain their powers once they phase out of their realm.  They would probably need a shard from dimension 1 in order to go back.

As for the second, the key aspects seem to be their fluid gassious forms and a focus on touch.  As such, finding cracks in their dimension and seeping through them seem like it would be a relatively easy to understand concept.  Some cracks may be harder to find than others, suggesting that some of these creatures might set up shop near the easiest to squeeze through cracks.

The third group is tricky because "tachyon" is a great buzzword with very little meaning, other than the fact that it propagates backwards in time.  However, if you were able to create a collision between this tachyonic matter and normal matter, all bets would be off on what would happen.  Propelling something into another dimension seems well within the reality of things, and if anyone disagrees, suggest that they bang together fireworks and a Tiki-torch for a bit and then come back to me when they find out just how much all bets are off when things collide!

The key to all of these is not that they are the "best" approach, merely that they are easy to understand based on what it appears you intend to write into your story.  As you go, you may find it useful to shift these ideas, or pick new ideas.  If you do, all you need to do is refer back to Sanderson's first law, and make sure that your reader understands what's going on beforehand.

Comment: I like this idea, but I was wondering if I could add this to it: Considering the first master race causes a lot of supernovas, which in turn cause black holes, is it possible for reality to be altered just enough that a crack could appear in the second dimension?

Comment: If you wanted to tie the stories together that way, it could work.  That could also be the source of the fragments of the 2nd dimension that appear in the 1st.  That actually helps with Sanderson's First Law, by tying things even more together.

Answer (score 0):

Mitochondria. Human cells each contain within them another cell which is a vestige of some early eukaryotic symbiosis. All eukaryotic cells of earth fauna share mitochondria. The mitochondria of your species are from a period before your dimensions split, and can therefore access all dimensions.

Comment: In other words: they have a thing called “handwavium” that allows them to break the plot barrier? This isn’t quite how physics or mitochondria work.

Comment: Obviously not. But this isn't about reality.. this is about worldbuilding

Comment: This doesn't wrap around my head. Doesn't that actually mean that every species has a part of another species inside of them in another dimension?

Comment: No. Every species has within it's cells, another primal species. Just as in our world all animal cells contain mitochondria.

Comment: @MansoorAhmad Mitochondria are the powerhouses of your cells.  Each cell has many of them to burn things like sugars to form molecules like ATP which are used by your cells to do things.  Mitochondria are actually believed to be derived from a single-celled organism which formed a symbiotic relationship.  In fact, mitochondria even have their own dna, which are inherited *differently* from the genetic material in the nucleus.  Their DNA is 100% inherited from the mother, 0% from the father.

Answer (score 0):

### The Dimensions are in neighboring areas in four-dimensional space

As an analogy: Let’s say that you live in New York, and you want to get to Los Angeles. How do you get there? Well, the simplest route is to fly, but if you want to take a longer route, you could drive. How would you drive? You would probably take I-80 to I-76 to I-70 to I-15 to - well, you get the idea.

In other words, to go from one place to another, you have to find a specific entry point (an airport or an on-ramp to a highway), navigate a particular route (or selection of routes), and then exit at a specific exit point (another airport or an off-ramp). If you make a wrong turn, you’re stuck in rural America, where the corn will be your friends for all eternity (or until AAA comes to save you).

A similar principle can be applied here. You have three Dimensions in four-dimensional space. In each one there is a place that acts as a wormhole through the dimensional fabric which allows one to travel into other Dimensions. Be warned, though - if you make a wrong turn, you’re stuck. That’s why, even though there are potentially infinite Dimensions, they only cross between these three, because those are the only ones they know how to get to and from.